# No menu bar, start button nor Terminal

Tags: unity, command-line

I have been using Ubuntu 13.04 for a few months now. But suddenly, I couldn't launch Terminal from the start or keyboard shortcut.

I tried rebooting, but now I cannot see the Menu bar and Start button. I managed to locate the Terminal by searching in the file system, but it returns "Error in launching the application".

I tried to reset Unity based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) but even Alt+F2 is not working. Really perplexed now, I dont know how to even turn off the system unless by force.

Would be really glad if someone could help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have fixed it now, but do not understand how. Will be awesome if someone can explain what went wrong...

First, opened Synaptic and installed gnome-terminal. After getting the Terminal back, neither `unity --reset` nor `unity --replace` worked. I wanted to check out the options for unity by typing `unity` and somehow got everything back (Menu bar, start button, applications, everything)

The output from Terminal for `unity` command is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5rtjUMduOGWYjRRb2VsMklDaVU/edit?usp=sharing).
And finally, I still get the following error upon starting the Terminal each time.

```
-bash: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt: No such file or directory
```

---

**Editors Addition:**

Those git related errors can be fixed by removing git bash-completion file using a command

```
rm -rf /etc/bash_completion.d/git
```

Check the related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451980/error-in-git-install-from-source-on-ubuntu

Comment: Sorry I don't remember now. I changed the laptop and OS after that. Do you think the question should be closed?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me... yes, I think it should be closed if we can't make sense of the answer (maybe it's just me though!)

Comment: @ManojKumar Typing `unity` will start unity, so you did what you needed to do, start it. And the errors probably because you were using some git-related bash modifications but later removed those. But left the sourcing line in your `.bashrc`, which resulted in "No such file ..." because you already removed them! You can either remove those lines from .bashrc or install again the git-sh-prompt

Comment: I see what had probably happened, it's much clearer now. Thank you